# A set of transitive sets has an $\in$-minimal element

Tags: set-theory

In "Fast Track to Forcing" Mirna Dzamonja, I have read that the Axiom of Foundation implies that

> $\in$ well-orders the universe of all transitive sets. $\quad(*)$

I'm now trying to check this claim. Transitivity and asymmetry are obvious. Next, the goal is to prove that any set of transitive sets has an $\in$-minimal element. Is this even true? Am I misunderstanding $(*)$?

Comment: That claim doesn't look right as stated... like for instance $V_3$ and $3$ are transitive sets that are not comparable by $\in.$ (Which is not to say the linked answer is wrong...)

Comment: Also, claims like "I have read..." are best backed up by a citation for context.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I have added some information. Thank you for your counter-example. Maybe the claim was just meant to state that any set has an $\in$-minimal element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regularity (Foundation),

$$\forall x\big(x\ne\varnothing\to\exists y\in x(y\cap x=\varnothing)\big)\,,$$

says that **every** non-empty set has an $\in$-minimal element: if $y\in x$, and $y\cap x=\varnothing$, then there is no $z\in x$ such that $z\in y$, and that makes $y$ an $\in$-minimal element of $x$ by definition.